# Is kinetic energy relative to a specific force?

Tags: energy

I have suddenly trouble understanding kinetic energy and why a moving particule have an energy.
I believe particules can only interact via forces. 
So to do work, at the end of the day a moving particule would need to apply some force in order to push another particule. But which force is it using? Like electromagnetism?
But then what if the particule is a neutrino or something...

Comment: The kinetic energy could be seen as the ability to transfer work to another body. Just because it isn't currently interacting does not mean it can't. That car coming down the road doesn't have to hit you for you to know that, should it do so, it will hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the kinetic energy of a moving mass is equal to the work it can do in coming to rest (in a chosen coordinate system).  The work can be done by any kind of force (but usually electrostatic). For a neutrino that might involve a direct collision with another sub-atomic particle.